# Rediccionar al login si no se inicio sesión

Tags: php

Tengo un sitio donde se puede acceder desde un Login, y esta separado por "administradores" y "usuarios" y algunos "permisos" de visualización del mismo sitio, ya que lo ven personas de diferentes areas. Lo que me piden es que si tengo la url especifica, poder saltear los menus e ir a esa sección, el tema lógicamente, no se inicio sesión y me manda:

> Undefined array key "autentica" in C:\Comedor-Test\Gestion de Comedores\ActiveDirectory\seguridad.php on line 4

tengo este codigo en esa parte:

```
<?php
@session_start();

if($_SESSION["autentica"] != "SIP"){
    header("Location: ../Login/");
    die();
}
```

?>

El tema que no lo envía al Login, me manda el error de arriba, hay forma de que si pongo una URL que no sea el Login, me compruebe el acceso y luego vaya a donde dice la URL? salteando los menú definidos por defecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la sesión no está iniciada va a dar error de variable no definida. Debería ser: `if(!isset($_SESSION["autentica"]))`

---

Lo siguiente es algo que no preguntaste, pero es relacionado y posiblemente te interese. Es posible que quieras regresar a la página solicitada una vez el usuario inició sesión:

1- El usuario escribe o hace clic en una url_directa
2- No está logueado y la página lo redirecciona a login.php
3- Una vez inicia sesión automáticamente se redirige a url del paso 1

Hay varias formas de resolver esto, pero esta es la más básica. Se considera también un patrón de diseño simple (no MVC o Framework).

Usemos por ejemplo: `http://mipagina.com/viewuser.php?uid=2634`

En la página viewuser.php:

```php
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["autentica"])) {
    // Usuario deslogueado.
    $ref = '?ref=viewuser.php';
    // [Opcional] Si se envia un parametro de usuario por la url: $_GET['uid']
    $ref .= isset($_GET['uid']) ? '&uid='.$_GET['uid'] : '';
    header("location:login.php".$ref); exit;
}
// ...
```

En login.php:

```php
<?php
// ...
// Capturar la url referida, de lo contrario usar index.php
$ref_url = isset($_GET['ref']) ? $_GET['ref'] : 'index.php';
// [Opcional] Capturar el parámetro del id del usuario 
$ref_url .= isset($_GET['uid']) ? '?uid='.$_GET['uid'] : '';

// ... logica del inicio de sesión
if(/* inicio de sesion correcto */) {
    header("location:$ref_url"); exit;
}
// ...
```

Como dije, esta es una forma muy básica. Si quieres puedes esconder la URL referida con un [encoder](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) y luego [decodificas](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) en login.php

Comment: excelente genio! muchas gracias!

Comment: Consulta en (inicio_sesion_correcto) que debería de ir?

Comment: @MatiasTonnera es solo una referencia que significa que el usuario se logueó correctamente, el resultado viene de la parte en donde inicias sesión, incluso podría ser alguna de las variables de sesión que ya hayan sido inicializadas correctamente, por ejemplo la propia `$_SESSION["autentica"]`. Lo editaré para que no cree confusiones.